# Can the word itinerary be used in context of an event schedule

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

What does the word **itinerary** mean? Can it be used in context of an event?

I looked up in dictionary and found its meaning as:

> the places you go to or plan to go to on journey

and also

> a document in which the places you will be going to are listed

But one of my friend is arguing me that it can be used as schedule for an event.

Comment: I just heard someone uses itinerary for an event schedule, I checked dictionary but I posted this just for clarification. Kindly answer. Sorry for the tag used, I was unaware of the tag usage on this platform.

Comment: "schedule for an event" concerns what is happening when, not where (those *places*). If that is not the case, you need to give a specific example.

Answer (score 1):

Properly used, "itinerary" should be used for the plan of a journey; it is a list of the places to visit.

But some people us it in a more general sense.  For example one website offers [wedding intineraries](https://www.thespruce.com/free-wedding-itinerary-templates-and-timelines-4147844) templates. This is an extension of its original meaning. Some would consider this to be incorrect.

So you *can* use "itinerary" to mean "schedule for event", but you *shouldn't*. Instead you should use "schedule", "plan", or "timeline" instead.

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary definition of "itinerary" is:

> A route or proposed route of a journey.

(https://www.thefreedictionary.com/itinerary)

That's essentially the same as the definition you found.

I have never heard someone use the word "itinerary" to mean the schedule of an event -- unless, of course, the "event" is a trip of some sort.

You certainly COULD use it to describe the schedule of an event as a metaphor of some kind. Like, "At this conference, we will be visiting many fields of science. The first stop on our itinerary is Chemistry. The second stop is Physics ..." etc. If the event is related to travel, like if it's a convention of travel agents, that might be clever and cute. But "cute" tends to get tiring after a while, so I'd be cautious about doing this.